# NOT IN filter in a query with a join of two collections using MongDB C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two collections that can be modelled with these classes (simplified version):

```
public class Profile
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }        
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }        
}
```

I need a query to get all the `UserProfiles` whose `User` has the `IsConfirmed` flag equals true, and then I need to filter out the ones whose Id is included in a list of excluded Ids:

```
IList<Guid> profileIdsToExclude
```

This is the query I've built so far:

```
var professionalProfilesQuery = 
    (from profileCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<Profile>("profiles").AsQueryable()
     join userCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<User>("users").AsQueryable()
     on profileCollection.UserId equals userCollection.Id.Value
     into users
     orderby profileCollection.Name
     select new ProfessionalProfile
     {
         Id = profileCollection.Id,
         Name = profileCollection.Name,                                                 
         UserId = profileCollection.UserId,
         IsConfirmed = users.First().IsConfirmed,                                                 
     })
     .Where(p => p.IsConfirmed && !profileIdsToExclude.Contains(p.Id.Value));
```

Where `ProfessionalProfile` is a class to return the query result:

```
public class ProfessionalProfile
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }        
}
```

I get UserProfiles, only the ones with `IsConfirmed` equals true. But the ones whose Id is in the list of excluded Ids are not filtered out and are returned by the query.

Any idea if what I want to do is possible and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is caused by a little type confusion.

The query that the driver creates contains a `$match` stage at the end that looks kind of like this:

```
{
    $match: {
        IsConfirmed: true,
        Id: {
            $nin: [ BinData(3, "DBA38D51FC28094BA2D6439E95643A49") ]
        }
    }
}
```

So it is actually trying to exclude results that have a field with a particular Guid value. You are, however, storing strings for your Guids so the filter does not exclude anything. In order to fix that here is what you could do:

Change

```
.Where(p => p.IsConfirmed && !profileIdsToExclude.Contains(p.Id.Value));
```

into

```
.Where(p => p.IsConfirmed && !profileIdsToExclude.Contains(p.Id));
```

and

```
IList<Guid> profileIdsToExclude
```

into

```
IList<Guid?> profileIdsToExclude
```